# How to delete all OSes on a computer except for one

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, uninstall

I want a simple way to delete all Oses off my computer except for one, that being Ubuntu. I also want to put all the remaining unallocated space onto the Ubuntu partition, so that it may have the original storage space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [gparted](http://gparted.org/) from the live CD.

The community wiki help contains some good explanations with examples about how to do it https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/

Last but not least, keep in mind that modifying partitions is a delicate task, so **backing up your data before is always a good idea.**

Comment: I don't want to resize the partitions, I want to delete/format them and put the remaining space onto the Ubuntu partition. I want to wipe them off. And I would rather do something simpler than Gparted.

Comment: How do you mean "simpler than gparted"?  I have been using Gparted for 10 years and it beats anything I ever used with Windows, including pay-for software?  Before I would post an answer to your question, I'd want to see a screenshot of how your partitions appear in gparted.  It could be that your drive is partitioned in such a way that you cannot simply "wipe" all other partitions off of it, and your best bet may be to clone the partition containing Ubuntu onto another drive.  If you are determined to seek a "simple" solution, please be sure to back up your data first.

Comment: @user364359 after you wipe off the old partitions, you need to resize the Ubuntu one in order to put the gained space there... Anyway, I updated my link. If you check it now, you'll see that there's is a page about deleting partitions too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OS-Uninstaller](http://sourceforge.net/p/os-uninstaller/wiki/Home/).

Download [Boot Repair Disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) ISO file, and burn it to CD.

Or

To install,  boot your computer with Ubunut live DVD or USB, and click on try Ubunutu.  Once booted, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install os-uninstaller
```